Unable to filter emails by multiple categories with Graph API
I am trying to filter emails by multiple categories with Microsoft Graph, but I'm not able to get it to work. I found this thread which gives me a query to filter by category 1 OR category 2:
$filter=categories/any(a:a eq 'Orange Category') OR categories/any(b:b eq 'Red Category')
I also found this thread which has the exact same problem as I do.
Here's the query they use:
$filter=categories/any(a:a eq 'Orange Category') AND categories/any(b:b eq 'Red Category')
Just as in that thread, I tried a similar query, and it just yields an empty array. It does not seem to work, and the link to a related GitHub issue is dead.
My mailbox has mails with category __One, mail with category _Two, mail with both categories, and mail with none or only the category "_Three".
What is wrong in my query and how can I filter emails by multiple categories with Microsoft Graph API? Is the problem the API itself or am I doing something wrong?
Here's the query I used in Graph Explorer that yields an empty array:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'__One')+AND+categories/any(b:b+eq+'_Two')
More info 08/05/2024:
I have been dealing with the issue for over a week. All I get is this JSON: { "@data.context": "url-here", "value": [] }. using 'OR' instead of 'AND' would return just fine the expected output, including emails with "categories": ["__One","_Two"]. Is there more information I could get to try to solve it? I am working with outlook for bussiness. the data.context` url doesn't seem to have anything useful. the problem persists in apparently all accounts on my organization
Update 21/05/2024
I am yet to find a solution. I decided to deprecate the feature for filtering by multiple categories. If you are having the same issue, I suggest trying to make a workaround yourself without relying on the graph api itself

I can't reproduce the issue. $filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'__One')+AND+categories/any(b:b+eq+'_Two') works fine and returns emails with both categories
